# question about php eval() function

Tags: php

i defined a couple of variables: $day_0, $day_1...$day_8 and need to build a string with those days variable embedded in the string, here is what i did;

```
for($i = 0; $i <=8; $i++) {
       $d = 'day_'.$i;
       $day = eval($($d));echo $day;
       $cmd_line .= 'INPUT'.$i.'='.$quote.$day.$quote.$space;
}
```

but php always complained

```
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'
```

what's wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: instead of defining named variables, you should define one array to hold them all. You can then cycle through the contents of the array quite easily. eval generally should not be used except in a few rare cases.

Comment: $day = array(); $day[0] = 'blah'; $day[1] = 'blah'; foreach($day as $value) {}

Comment: This usage of eval is indicative that you skipped over this important section in the PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Three answers, two of which upvoted, all suggesting the thinly-veiled restricted `eval`-nephew that are variable variables instead of going for te obvious, easier, more acceptable array solution. And you wonder why PHP has a bad reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A safer and easier solution would be to use:

```
$d = 'day_'.$i;
$day = $$d;
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `eval`:

```
for($i = 0; $i <=8; $i++) {
       $day = ${'day_' . $i};
       echo $day;
       $cmd_line .= 'INPUT'.$i.'='.$quote.$day.$quote.$space;
}
```

See the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for more information on variable variables.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `$$` ?

```
for($i = 0; $i <=8; $i++) {
       $d = 'day_'.$i;
       $day = $$d; //this will point to $day_0 ...
       echo $day;
       $cmd_line .= 'INPUT'.$i.'='.$quote.$day.$quote.$space;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest `eval()` but if you want to use it pass valid php code as `eval()` parameter (string).

**Example:**

```
$d = 'day_1';
$phpcode = "\${$d}='something';";
$day = eval($phpcode);
echo $day_1;
```

This will print out string `something` assigned to new variable `$day_1`.

Don't forget to add `;` at the and of every line you want to evaluate using `eval()` function.

Array would be better solution.